# Using += in scriptblock for a switch statement in a foreach loop

Tags: arrays, powershell, foreach, switch-statement

Firstly, thank you for taking the time to read this, thank you for your help in advance.

Here is my code:

```
<#
        SCCM Request Alert Script
#>
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$WMIObjects = Get-WmiObject -Namespace 'ROOT\SMS\Site_EUR' -Class SMS_UserApplicationRequest -ComputerName "EUR-SCCM"
$FileStore = "c:\export\SCCMRequestfile.txt"
foreach ($Obj in $WMIObjects)
{
        [String]$RequestValue = $Obj.CurrentState
        $Application = $Obj.Application
        $User = $Obj.User -replace 'MYDOMAIN\\',""
        $ADUser = Get-ADUser -Identity $User
        $PendingRequest = @()
        $CancelledRequest = @()
        $DeniedRequest = @()
        $ApprovedRequest = @()
        $Unknown = @()

        $Args = @{ 'User' = $ADUser.Name; 'Application' = $Obj.Application }

        $PR = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Args
        $CR = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Args
        $DR = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Args
        $AR = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Args
        $UR = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Args

        switch ($RequestValue) {
                1 { $PendingRequest += $PR }
                2 { $CancelledRequest += $CR }
                3 { $DeniedRequest += $DR }
                4 { $ApprovedRequest += $AR }
        default { $Unknown += $UK }
        }


}

Write-Host -ForegroundColor 'yellow' "Pending Requests "
$PendingRequest
Write-Host -ForegroundColor 'DarkYellow'  "Cancelled Requests "
$CancelledRequest
Write-Host -ForegroundColor 'DarkRed' "Denied Requests "
$DeniedRequest
Write-Host -ForegroundColor 'Green' "Approved Requests "
$ApprovedRequest
Write-Host -ForegroundColor 'White' "Unknown Approval Type "
$Unknown
```

At them moment it only returns the last object in the foreach loop.

I've tested a foreach loop manually using;

```
foreach ($Obj in $Objects) {

$array = @()

$array += $Obj

}

$Array
```

And this places each object in the the array.

So I was wondering if this was an issue with the switch statement or something I haven't done like casting it as an array?

Any help would be appreciate, Thank you.

Nigel Tatschner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're re-initializing your arrays on each iteration of the loop. Move the following lines so they're **before** your `foreach` loop:

```
$PendingRequest = @();
$CancelledRequest = @();
$DeniedRequest = @();
$ApprovedRequest = @();
$Unknown = @();
```